# Void function: returning garbage from an array variable to main in C

Tags: c

I need some help

I want my void function to display the correct output instead of garbage, I'm still halfway of my current program. I want to know if

```
void expand(char r[7], char *eR){

    //  static char temp[10];
        *(eR+0) = r[0];
        *(eR+1) = r[1];
        *(eR+2) = r[3];
        *(eR+3) = r[2];
        *(eR+4) = r[3];
        *(eR+5) = r[2];
        *(eR+6) = r[4];
        *(eR+7) = r[5];
        *(eR+8) = '\0';

        printf("Expanded: %s",eR);

    }

int main(){
    char bitMessage[13],key[10],l[7],r[7],xResult,eR[9];
    char *temp=eR;
    int i;
    char *fResult;
    printf("Enter Message:");
    scanf("%s",&bitMessage);
    printf("Enter Key:");
    scanf("%s",&key);

    printf("Message is %s \n",bitMessage);
    printf("Key is %s \n",key);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("LEFT:");
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        printf("%c",bitMessage[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("RIGHT:");
    for(i=6;i<12;i++){
        printf("%c",bitMessage[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Key:");
    for(i=0;i<10-1;i++){
        printf("%c",key[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    expand(r,eR);


    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5bya.png)

Please help me to get through this and I am still new in programming

Comment: I don't see where you fill `r` with anything.

Comment: what do you mean sir?

Comment: `r` is never used before the call to `expand()`. It is _uninitialized_ and can have anything in it. That's why you are seeing junk characters.

Comment: Ok i see the point now so how am I gonna use the variable r in the code ? I want to use it in my forloop for the right to display the numbers.

Comment: I revised my code of the for-loop before to this and it didn't give me garbage anymore but it still doesn't display the output.                                                                                
     <pre>   printf("LEFT:");
 for(i=0;i<6;i++){
  l[7]=bitMessage[i];
  printf("%c",l[7]);
 }
 printf("\n");
 printf("RIGHT:");
 for(i=6;i<12;i++){
  r[7]=bitMessage[i];
  printf("%c",r[7]);
 } <code>

Comment: `scanf("%s",&bitMessage);` should be `scanf("%12s",bitMessage);` . There is a similar bug with the next scanf

Comment: Please post code changes as edits to the question and not as a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `r` and `l`. I *think* you want this:

```
printf("LEFT:");
// Copy chars bitMessage 0-5 to l 0-5
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    l[i] = bitMessage[i];
    printf("%c", l[i]);
}
printf("\n");
printf("RIGHT:");
// Copy chars bitMessage 6-11 to r 0-5
for(i = 6; i < 12; i++){
    r[i - 6] = bitMessage[i];
    printf("%c", r[i - 6]);
}
```

Comment: if this answer helped you, please upvote it and accept it